# How much destructive the earlier weapons were?

Tags: weapon

We often hear of various weapons used by various Gods and different other people, which are said to be almost undefeatable. I want to know is there anything written in texts describing these weapons such as Sudarshana Chakra, Lord Shiva's trishul, Lord Shiva's bow, Pashupatastra, Narayanastra, Bramhastra, Indra's Vajra, etc. I mean how they were structured, how much destructive they were, who was their creator, what all were required to operate them.

Comment: You know, [this blog](http://decodehindumythology.blogspot.in/2015/04/war-of-worlds_11.html) makes an interesting read.

Comment: First of all a supernatural weapon is something very different as compared to a physical weapon. Secondly, the creators are the devas themselves. Thirdly, their power differs. A supernatural weapon can only be stopped by another supernatural weapon.

Answer (score 3):

In Ramayana a mention was made about Indrajit, who used brahmAstra for **mass destruction**. It eliminated ***67 crores of Vanaras*** on a particular day.

> भिन्नलाङ्गूलहस्तोरुपादाङ्गुलि शिरो धरैः | स्रवद्भिः क्षतजं गात्रैः
>   प्रस्रवद्भिः समन्ततः || ६-७४-८
>
> पतितैः पर्वताकारैर्वानरैरभिसङ्कुलाम् | शस्त्रैश्च
>   पतितैर्दीप्तैर्ददृशाते वसुन्धराम् || ६-७४-९
>
> Hanuma and Vibhishana saw the battle-field, covered on all sides, with
>   mountain-sized monkeys fallen with heir tails, arms, thighs, feet,
>   fingers and heaps of heads fractured with blood oozing from their
>   limbs and urine flowing out. The earth was also covered with flaming
>   weapons fallen around.
>
> सप्तषष्टिर्हताः कोट्यो वानराणां तरस्विनाम् | अह्नः पञ्चमशेषेण वल्लभेन
>   स्वयम्भुवः || ६-७४-१२
>
> Sixty seven crores of powerful monkeys were struck down by the
>   cherished missile of Brahma, the self-born creator, in the fifth and
>   last period of the day.

This was the mass destruction by **brahmAstra** mentioned in Ramayana.

---

Comment: Interesting. That figure of 67 crore vaanaras is half the size of the Indian population in 2020. Does stretch credulity somewhat.

Comment: @iruvar, yes. pretty much everything in Ramayana stretches credulity, because it is an account of avataras of Bhagavan and Devas, who, by definition, are beyond the credulity of humans.